# Haskell type keyword used with signature

Tags: haskell, types, signature, ghci

In [the code from *Scrap Your Zippers*](https://michaeldadams.org/papers/scrap_your_zippers/ScrapYourZippers.hs), what does the following line mean:

```
type Move a = Zipper a -> Maybe (Zipper a)
```

*Type* is a synonym for a type and uses the same data constructors, so this make no sense.  How is it used here?

Comment: It's a type synonym (or type alias).  It simply means anywhere you see `Move X` you can mentally substitute that with `Zipper X -> Maybe (Zipper X)`.

Comment: I didn't knew it can also be used as an type alias for the signature. It is all clear now, thanks!

Comment: @user2340939 That's really the only thing it can be used for. A signature is just a type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "data" and "type" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316533/whats-the-difference-between-data-and-type-keywords)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type` allows us to make synonyms, as you say. This means we can make shortened versions of long and complicated types. Here is the definition of the `String` base type. Yes, this is how it's defined:

```
type String = [Char]
```

This allows us to make types more readable when we write them; everyone prefers seeing `String` to `[Char]`.

You can also have type arguments like in the `data` keyword. Here are some Examples:

```
type Predicate t = t -> Bool
type Transform t = t -> t
type RightFoldSignature a b = (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
type TwoTuple a b = (a,b)
type ThreeTuple a b c = (a,b,c)
```

... And so on. So, there's nothing particularly strange going on with the declaration you have there - the author is making a type synonym to make things easier to write and clearer to read, presumably to be used in the types of the functions the author wants to create.

Learn you a Haskell has it's [own little section](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#type-synonyms) on this, a list of the different declarations can be found [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html), and an article [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.4/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html).

Comment: One more question: would the function moveQ :: Move a -> b -> (Zipper a -> b) -> Zipper a -> b translate to moveQ :: Zipper a -> Maybe (Zipper a) -> b -> (Zipper a -> b) -> Zipper a -> b or to moveQ :: (Zipper a -> Maybe (Zipper a)) -> b -> (Zipper a -> b) -> Zipper a -> b, that is, to a fonction parameter?

Comment: @user2340939 No - it will behave in a way similar to `(a -> b) -> c`, because `a -> b -> c` is equivalent to `a -> (b -> c)`. Think of expanding it into brackets.