# What's the difference between the "data" and "type" keywords?

Tags: haskell, keyword

The `data` and `type` keywords always confuse me.

I want to know what is the difference between `data` and `type` and how to use them.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`type` declares a *type synonym*. A type synonym is a new name for an existing type. For example, this is how `String` is defined [in the standard library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#String):

```
type String = [Char]
```

`String` is another name for a list of `Char`s. GHC will replace all usages of `String` in your program with `[Char]` at compile-time.

To be clear, a `String` *literally is* a list of `Char`s. It's just an alias. You can use all the standard list functions on `String` values:

```
-- length :: [a] -> Int
ghci> length "haskell"
7
-- reverse :: [a] -> [a]
ghci> reverse "functional"
"lanoitcnuf"
```

---

`data` declares a *new data type*, which, unlike a type synonym, is different from any other type. Data types have a number of *constructors* defining the possible cases of your type. For example, this is how `Bool` is defined [in the standard library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Bool.html#t:Bool):

```
data Bool = False | True
```

A `Bool` value can be either `True` or `False`. Data types support *pattern matching*, allowing you to perform a runtime case-analysis on a value of a data type.

```
yesno :: Bool -> String
yesno True = "yes"
yesno False = "no"
```

`data` types can have multiple constructors (as with `Bool`), can be parameterised by other types, can contain other types inside them, and can recursively refer to themselves. Here's a model of exceptions which demonstrates this; an `Error a` contains an error message of type `a`, and possibly the error which caused it.

```
data Error a = Error { value :: a, cause :: Maybe (Error a) }
type ErrorWithMessage = Error String

myError1, myError2 :: ErrorWithMessage
myError1 = Error "woops" Nothing
myError2 = Error "myError1 was thrown" (Just myError1)
```

It's important to realise that `data` declares a new type which is apart from any other type in the system. If `String` had been declared as a `data` type *containing* a list of `Char`s (rather than a type synonym), you wouldn't be able to use any list functions on it.

```
data String = MkString [Char]
myString = MkString ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
myReversedString = reverse myString  -- type error
```

---

There's one more variety of type declaration: `newtype`. This works rather like a `data` declaration - it introduces a new data type separate from any other type, and can be pattern matched - except you are restricted to a single constructor with a single field. In other words, a `newtype` is a `data` type which wraps up an existing type.

The important difference is the *cost* of a `newtype`: the compiler promises that a `newtype` is represented in the same way as the type it wraps. There's no runtime cost to packing or unpacking a `newtype`. This makes `newtype`s useful for making *administrative* (rather than *structural*) distinctions between values.

`newtype`s interact well with type classes. For example, consider `Monoid`, the class of types with a way to combine elements (`mappend`) and a special 'empty' element (`mempty`). `Int` can be made into a `Monoid` in many ways, including addition with 0 and multiplication with 1. How can we choose which one to use for a possible `Monoid` instance of `Int`? It's better not to express a preference, and use `newtype`s to enable either usage with no runtime cost. Paraphrasing [the standard library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Data.Monoid.html#Sum):

```
-- introduce a type Sum with a constructor Sum which wraps an Int, and an extractor getSum which gives you back the Int
newtype Sum = Sum { getSum :: Int }
instance Monoid Sum where
    (Sum x) `mappend` (Sum y) = Sum (x + y)
    mempty = Sum 0

newtype Product = Product { getProduct :: Int }
instance Monoid Product where
    (Product x) `mappend` (Product y) = Product (x * y)
    mempty = Product 1
```

Comment: a possible edit: "it's better not to freeze-in an implicit preference and use `newtype`s to *express* each possible choice *explicitly,* with no runtime cost".

Answer (score 2):

With `data` you create **new** datatype and declare a constructor for it:

```
data NewData = NewDataConstructor
```

With `type` you define just an alias:

```
type MyChar = Char
```

In the `type` case you can pass value of `MyChar` type to function expecting a `Char` and vice versa, but you can't do this for `data MyChar = MyChar Char`.

Answer (score 2):

`type` works just like `let`: it allows you to give a re-usable name to something, but that something will always work just as if you had inlined the definition. So

```
type ℝ = Double

f :: ℝ -> ℝ -> ℝ
f x y = let x2 = x^2
        in x2 + y
```

behaves exactly the same way as

```
f' :: Double -> Double -> Double
f' x y = x^2 + y
```

as in: you can anywhere in your code replace `f` with `f'` and vice versa; nothing would change.

OTOH, both `data` and `newtype` create an opaque *abstraction*. They are more like a class constructor in OO: even though some value is *implemented* simply in terms of a single number, it doesn't necessarily *behave* like such a number. For instance,

```
newtype Logscaledℝ = LogScaledℝ { getLogscaled :: Double }

instance Num LogScaledℝ where
  LogScaledℝ a + LogScaledℝ b = LogScaledℝ $ a*b
  LogScaledℝ a - LogScaledℝ b = LogScaledℝ $ a/b
  LogScaledℝ a * LogScaledℝ b = LogScaledℝ $ a**b
```

Here, although `Logscaledℝ` is data-wise still just a `Double` number, it clearly behaves different from `Double`.